Calculating with an overall maximum value
A problem arose with calculating the linear equation. Here's the essence. For example, we sold 20 cars from 08/01/2024 to 08/15/2024, and we need to forecast the sales using the formula: 20/15*31, where 20 is the number of cars, 15 is the number of days passed, and 31 is the total number of days in the month.
In SQL, it looks like this:
ROUND(SUM(C.CAR_COUNT) / EXTRACT(DAY FROM MAX(D.DAY_DT)) * EXTRACT(DAY FROM LAST_DAY(MIN(D.DAY_DT))), 0) AS CAR_PREDICTION,

But the problem is that there are many points of sale, and each has a different MAX(D.DAY_DT), while we need to make sure all sales are multiplied by the last day, i.e., 15.
What complicates the task further is that the value needs to be dynamic, so hardcoding 15 is not an option.
Perhaps someone has some ideas.
ROUND(SUM(C.CAR_COUNT) / EXTRACT(DAY FROM MAX(D.DAY_DT)) * EXTRACT(DAY FROM LAST_DAY(MIN(D.DAY_DT))), 0) AS CAR_PREDICTION 
or 
ROUND(SUM(C.CAR_COUNT) / EXTRACT(DAY FROM MIN(D.DAY_DT)) * EXTRACT(DAY FROM LAST_DAY(MIN(D.DAY_DT))), 0) AS CAR_PREDICTION

Don`t work

You have something like this:
SELECT
  point_of_sale,
  ROUND(SUM(c.car_count) / 
    EXTRACT(DAY FROM MAX(d.day_dt)) * 
    EXTRACT(DAY FROM LAST_DAY(MAX(d.day_dt)))
    , 0) AS car_prediction
FROM ...
GROUP BY point_of_sale;

But instead of using the MAX(d.day_dt) per point of sale, you want to use an overall MAX(d.day_dt). The maximum of the maximums so to say. This is:
MAX(MAX(d.day_dt)) OVER ()

So, the query becomes:
SELECT
  point_of_sale,
  ROUND(SUM(c.car_count) / 
    EXTRACT(DAY FROM MAX(MAX(d.day_dt)) OVER ()) * 
    EXTRACT(DAY FROM LAST_DAY(MAX(MAX(d.day_dt)) OVER ()))
    , 0) AS car_prediction
FROM ...
GROUP BY point_of_sale;

